# andmap and null? returning false

Tags: null, scheme, racket

I want to determine whether a list contains only `null`.  `null?` seems like the obvious choice:

```
> (null? null)
#t
```

But `andmap`ing over it is not doing what I'd expect:

```
> (andmap null? '(null))
#f
```

Am I misunderstanding `null?` or `andmap`?  I'm new to Racket, but this just doesn't seem right at all based on the docs.

Comment: FWIW, as a former C/C++ guy, `null` and `null?` have misleading connotations for me. I prefer to use `'()` or `(list)` for an empty list, and `empty?` as the predicate.

Comment: @GregHendershott Good point!  I hadn't come across `empty?` yet, but that does make a lot more sense to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that `'(null)` is *not* a list containing `null` (i.e., the empty list). Here are a few options that will work:

- `(andmap null? '(()))`
- `` (andmap null? `(,null)) `` or `(andmap null? (quasiquote (unquote null)))`
- `(andmap null? (list null))`.

Explanation of what's going on: the identifier `null` is bound to a value representing the empty list. When you do `'null`, this is equivalent to `(quote null)` which means "give me a symbol representing the identifier, not what it represents" (like quoting in natural language).

You can avoid this by using the literal that represents null `'()` or by using `quasiquote` and `unquote` to "escape" back to Racket.

For more information about quoting, see the [Guide entry](http://pre.racket-lang.org/docs/html/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html?q=quotation#%28part._quoting-lists%29) on it.

Comment: Thanks.  This makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with `andmap`, or with `null?`. It's the way you're constructing the list that's wrong. In fact, this list: `'(null)` is equivalent to this: `(list 'null)`:

```
(equal? '(null) (list 'null))
=> #t
```

And `'null` is not the same as `null`:

```
(equal? 'null null)
=> #f
```

So, what we need is a correct way to express a null value inside a list. Any of the following will work:

```
(andmap null? '(()))
=> #t
(andmap null? (quote (())))
=> #t
(andmap null? (list '()))
=> #t
(andmap null? (list null))
=> #t
(andmap null? `(,null))
=> #t
(andmap null? (quasiquote (unquote null)))
=> #t
```